# Program does not ask questions about user's age

Tags: c++

I am 14 and it is my first time programming.

I've tried to make this basic C++ program which asks a few questions about yourself:

```
int main()
{
    int getInt(std::istream & is);
    std::string input;
    std::getline(is,input);
    return stoi(input);

    int age;
    string name, team, correct;
    cout << "What's your name? ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Hello " << name << ".\n";
    cout << "What is your favorite team? ";
    cin >> team;
    cout << "How old are you? ";
    cin >> age;
    cout << "So you are " << age << " called " << name << " and support " << team << ".\n";
    cout << "Is this correct? ";
    cin >> correct;

    if (correct == "yes")
    {
        cout << "Okay nice";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Please say yes next time";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The main issues is that it will not ask for my age. I have tried taking out the age part and then it works for the most part.

The second thing I need help with is the if-else statement. I want it to be so that if I say "yes" then it will say "okay nice", but if I say anything else, I want it to say "Please say yes next time."

This would be the base for more small projects, so help would be greatly appreciated, thank you :D

Comment: `return stoi(input);`  The rest of the code will never be reached.  A little consistent formatting in your code goes a long way.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Since it appears that you're looking to learn C++, I'd recommend looking at a few tutorials or picking up a book to read ([this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512195/what-would-be-a-good-free-c-e-book-or-tutorial-series-preferably-text) has several for you to look at). If you're still not quite getting the hang of it, I'd suggest you find a different language to start off with, then you can come back to C++ when you're able to understand the general concepts of programming better.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that he program is not asking for your age is because it encountered

```
return stoi(input);
```

A `return` statement is used to give the function a value ( or something else depending on the type of the function ) , and whenever a `return` is encountered, the function exits.

That's what's happening in your code, `main()` exits when it encounters that `return`.

Now, this code will work as you expect it to if you remove

```
int getInt(std::istream & is);
std::string input;
std::getline(is,input);
return stoi(input);
```

from your code. You don't need that for your code to work here. ( It will compile and work without problems )

I assume you were expecting to make that into a function and use it to convert `age` into an integer. But it will work as a string here.